# Enabling GPU in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, gpu

I have a problem enabling gpu in silverlight. I added the param but I do not find it in the permission tab in the Silverlight Configuration. The gpu is security blocked. I have also tried running out-of-browser but still the gpu is security blocked.

Comment: Do you have the line `<param name="enableGPUAcceleration" value="true" />` in your `<object>` definition? Why do you say that "GPU is security blocked".

Comment: yes I did. I used the GraphicsDeviceManager.RenderModeReason and it showed security blocked

Comment: Hmm - not familiar with that, sorry.

Comment: Also having the same problem. Did you find a solution. I have tried everything I can think of so far - cannot get GPU acceleration to work. Still researching - suspect group policy now or virus scanner.

Comment: Dude, I gave up silverlight 3 months ago. Silverlight will be abandoned in a few years (more like 2 or 3).

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the usual things to get this to work, but what eventually solved the issue was in the silverlight project setting "Require Elevated trust when running in browser"

Answer (score -1):

[This blog post](http://www.yvision.com/2012/02/14/quirks-on-silverlight-5-with-gpu-acceleration/) possibly gives you the answers you are looking for. Excerpt:

*When entering your web site the user will have to:*

- Right click on the Silverlight plugin and a context menu will appear.
- Click on the “Silverlight” menu item.
- Open to the “Permissions” tab.
- Look for the host address of the page you’re visiting.
- Select the “3D Graphics: use blocked display drivers” option , that should have “Denied” right in front of it.
- Click on the button “Allow” located after the list.
- Click on “OK” top close the dialog and then [...] you’ll have to reload the page.

Comment: The problem is that the permission doesn't exist there.

Comment: Could you please elaborate with for example extracts from configuration files, code or screen dumps exactly what you have tried and how the security block is shown.

Answer (score -1):

To run it out-of-browser with GPU hardware acceleration you have to explicitly specify the settings in your deployment XAML file like given below.

```
    <OutOfBrowserSettings 
        EnableGPUAcceleration="True"
     <OutOfBrowserSettings.Blurb>
```

In browser issue can solved by enabling hardware acceleration for the silverlight plug-in as answered above.